# Get method's name using __getattribute__ without type error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print method's name using `__getattribute__`

but I get typeerror everytime I called the method, and the method is not excuted, is there anyway to get rid of the type error and have the method excuted ?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super()

    def test(self):
        print(1)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        print(attr)



p = Person()

p.test()
```

The above code gives the error

```
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 15, in <module>
    p.test()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Is there anyway to print the method's name only without giving the error ?

I tried to catch typeError inside `__getattribute__` method, but it doesn't work

Another question is, why it says `None Type object is not callable` here

Thank you !

Ps. I know I can catch the error when I call the method, I mean is there anyway to deal this error inside `__getattribute` method? since my goal is to print method's name everytime a method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second question first, why is it saying NoneType not callable.

When you call `p.test()` Python tries to lookup the `test` attribute of the `p` instance. It calls the `__getattribute__` method that you've overridden which prints 'test' and then returns. Because you're not returning anything it implicitly returns `None`. `p.test` is therefore `None` and calling it gives the error you get.

So how do we fix this? Once you've printed the attribute name, you need to return the attribute you're after. You can't just call `getattr(self, attr)` or you'll end up in an infinite loop so you have to call the method that would have been called if you hadn't overridden it.

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    print(attr)
    return super().__getattribute__(attr) # calls the original method
```

Comment: Thank you ! very clear explanation, and the code works !